# Error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'string[]

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

sorry for my bad English.

I am having problems when it comes to passing values from my Windows form to the class definition I made.

I have declared seven arrays in my class definition in an attempt to store the values passed from the said windows form. My problem is that I am constantly getting an error like

`Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'string[]'`

I have tried to get an idea on another work that was give to me but it seems that it is still throwing errors on my work.

Here is my class definition:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace BankTransaction
{

public class Transactions
{
    String username, password;
    decimal deposit, withdrawal, balance;
    decimal percentInterest;
    private decimal projectedInterest;
    private String uname;
    public string fName, lName, mInitial, pword, actType, uName;
    const Int64 MAX_SIZE = Int64.MaxValue;

    public static String[] firstName = new String [MAX_SIZE];
    public static String[] lastName = new String[MAX_SIZE];
    public static String[] mi = new String[MAX_SIZE];
    public static String[] pass = new String[MAX_SIZE];
    public static String[] userName = new String[MAX_SIZE];
    public static String[] accountType = new String[MAX_SIZE];
    public static decimal[] deposito = new decimal[MAX_SIZE];
    static int count = 0;
    public static int that;
    public static int number = 10001;

    public void registerLoginDetails()
    {
        firstName[count] = fName;
        lastName[count] = lName;
        mi[count] = mInitial;
        pass[count] = pword;
        accountType[count] = actType;
        userName[count] = uName;
        deposito[count] = deposit;
        count++;
        number++;
    }

    public decimal computeProjectedInterest(decimal initialBalance, decimal numOfYears)
    {

        if (numOfYears < 1)
        {
            percentInterest = 0.00m;
        }

        if (numOfYears > 0 && numOfYears <= 3)
        {
            percentInterest = 0.02m;
        }

        if (numOfYears > 3 && numOfYears <= 5)
        {
            percentInterest = 0.05m;
        }

        if (numOfYears > 5 && numOfYears <=10)
        {
            percentInterest = 0.08m;
        }

        if (numOfYears > 10)
        {
            percentInterest = 0.12m;
        }

        projectedInterest = initialBalance * percentInterest * numOfYears;
        return projectedInterest;
    }

    public decimal withdrawBalance()
    {
        return 0m;
    }

    public decimal depositBalance()
    {
        return 0m;
    }
}
}
```

And here is my code for the said WinForm:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using BankTransaction;

namespace LabExam1
{
public partial class Registration : Form
{

    const long size = Int64.MaxValue;
    public static Transactions trans = new Transactions();
    int i = 0;

    public void confirmRegistration()
    {

        Transactions.firstName = txtFname.Text;
        Transactions.lastName = txtLname.Text;
        Transactions.mi = txtMi.Text;
        Transactions.pass = txtPass.Text;
        Transactions.deposito = nudDeposit.Value;
        Transactions.accountType = cboType.Text;
        Transactions.userName = "";
        trans.registerLoginDetails();
        i++;


        this.Hide();
        Login lo = new Login();
        lo.ShowDialog();
    }

    public Registration()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cboType.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }

    private void btnRegister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtFname.Text == "" || txtLname.Text == "" || txtMi.Text == "" || txtPass.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please fill up all required fields!", "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        }
        else
        {
            if (cboType.SelectedIndex == 0)
            {
                confirmRegistration();
            }

            if (cboType.SelectedIndex == 1)
            {
                if (nudDeposit.Value < 2500.00m)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("The initial deposit for your account type is insufficient", "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                }

                else
                {
                    confirmRegistration();
                }
            }

            if (cboType.SelectedIndex == 2)
            {
                if (nudDeposit.Value < 3000.00m)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("The initial deposit for your account type is insufficient", "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                }

                else
                {
                    confirmRegistration();
                }
            }
        }


    }

    private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }

    private void btnGotoLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
        Login lo = new Login();
        lo.ShowDialog();
    }

}
```

}

Thanks in advance to everyone that will answer my question.

Comment: At which line do you get the exception?

Comment: Really 7 arrays of Int64.MaxValue? I think you have a bigger problem here

Comment: In the lines that look like this:
 Transactions.firstName = txtFname.Text;

You are attempting to put a string into a string array (string[]).
I am not sure what your intent is but you need to put the string into a position in the array like such:
 Transactions.firstName[position] = txtFname.Text;

Answer (score 2):

When setting the public properties of the static `Transactions` object (a horrible design, BTW, but I assume you're still learning...)  you're trying to set the public array properties instead of the individual value properties:

```
    Transactions.firstName = txtFname.Text;
    Transactions.lastName = txtLname.Text;
    Transactions.mi = txtMi.Text;
    Transactions.pass = txtPass.Text;
    Transactions.deposito = nudDeposit.Value;
    Transactions.accountType = cboType.Text;
    Transactions.userName = "";
```

should be

```
    Transactions.fName = txtFname.Text;
    Transactions.lName = txtLname.Text;
    Transactions.mInitial = txtMi.Text;
    Transactions.pword = txtPass.Text;
    Transactions.deposit = nudDeposit.Value;
    Transactions.actType = cboType.Text;
    Transactions.uName = "";
```

That solves the *compiler* errors but does not address the *design* issues.  If this is a learning project that's forgivable but there are several design issues that should be addressed at some point (possibly on [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)).

Answer (score 0):

Look at your code

```
Transactions.firstName = txtFname.Text;
Transactions.lastName = txtLname.Text;
Transactions.mi = txtMi.Text;
Transactions.pass = txtPass.Text;
Transactions.deposito = nudDeposit.Value;
Transactions.accountType = cboType.Text;
```

You are directly setting an array of String with a String variable, try using an index.

```
    Transactions.firstName[index] = txtFname.Text;
    Transactions.lastName[index] = txtLname.Text;
...
```